# using cumax for making a new column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 4 columns in my data set. first number of family, second number of persons in that family,  col3 is the number of trips that a person make, col4 the place of the activity of that person and col5 is something that I am want to make .

```
 family   persons    trip      activity       
     1     1        1         home
     1     1        2         shopping
     1     1        3          home
     1     1        4         eating
     1     1        5         friends
     1     1        6          home
     1     2        1          home
     1     2        2           eating
     1     2        3           work
     1     2        3           shopping
```

as you can see in the above data set we have information of 2 persons in the first family. first person has 6 trips and the second one 3 trips. home and work is important in my analysis. I want to make loop based on home and work activity. in other words each loop is a set of activities that start at home and finish at home or work. for the first person we have 2 loops :

```
  first loop: home-> shopping -> home
  second loop: home -> eating -> freinds ->home
```

for second person we have 2 loops

```
   loop: home -> eating ->work
   loop2: work ->shopping
```

I want to add a column that determine the number of loop in this data set like this :

```
 family persons   trip       place       loop
   1      1        1         home          1
   1      1        2        shopping       1
   1      1        3         home          1
   1      1        4         eating        2  
   1      1        5         friends       2 
   1      1        6          home         2
   1      2        1          home         1
   1      2        2           eating      1
   1      2        3           work        1
   1      2        3           shopping    2
```

I have the following code:

```
vals <- c("work","home")

library(dplyr)
 df9<-df1 %>% 
  group_by(SAMPN,PERNO) %>% 
  mutate(loop = cummax(lag(1 + (TPURP %in% vals), default = 1)))
```

But it doesn't give me the correct output. when there are 2 home for one person it doesn't change the loop. For example for first person it is all 1 in loop.

Comment: `cummax` seems like an odd choice. `TPURP %in% vals` gives a logical result, (1/0), so when you add 1 to it it will be either 2 or 1. It's impossible for it to take a value > 2, and so `cummax` will never go greater than 2. Maybe try `cumsum` instead of `cummax`, with a `default = 0` for the lag?

Comment: I tried it but gives me so wrong output.

Comment: I concur with @Gregor that this is a job for `cumsum`. `lag(cumsum(TPURP %in% vals), default = 1)` should do it.